# Passing binary data to a python logger

Tags: python, logging

I want to log raw bytes. But if I change the file mode in FileHandler from "w" to "wb" the logger fails with error, whichever data I pass to it: string or bytes.

```
logging.getLogger("clientIn").error(b"bacd")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
Call stack:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 119, in _main
    return self._bootstrap()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/serj/work/proxy_mult/proxy/connection_worker_process.py", line 70, in __call__
    self._do_work(ipc_socket)
  File "/home/serj/work/proxy_mult/proxy/connection_worker_process.py", line 76, in _do_work
    logging.getLogger("clientIn").error("bacd")
Message: 'bacd'
```

I need the way to adapt logging module to binary data.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this problem eventually? A work-around is decoding the binary data with Latin-1 and accordingly opening the log file with Latin-1 encoding, but it's not a very elegant solution.

Comment: No, I got away with plain `write`. In your solution do you mean you will see the same logged data in text editor text mode the same as if you were seeing the (non-decoded) output in binary mode?

Comment: If you send `bytes` objects to the logger, I guess you'll see the data wrapped in `b'...'` and with all non-ASCII characters escaped with backslashes. With the Latin-1 trick, the data will be written to the output literally, ie. if you open it with an editor (using Latin-1 encoding), you'll see gibberish including accented letters and maybe boxes for control codes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no "point" in logging raw bytes. You have to answer the question of what your data is encoded as. If you want to write the raw bytes message to file, you are just moving the problem down the road (what is the file encoded as?). The closest you can come is logging `str(your_bytes)` or `list(your_bytes)`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to store the bytes in a bytestring.

The other possible way is to customize your logging. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) is a start but you will need to look into examples of how people have done it. Personally I have gone only as far as to using a slightly customized record, handler and formatter for allowing my logger to use a SQLite backend.

There are multiple things you need to modify (sorry for not being that specific but I am also still a beginner when it comes to the logging module of Python):

- `LogRecord` - if you inherit from it, you will see that the `__init__(...)` specifies an argument `msg` of type `object`. As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord) states `msg` is **the event description message, possibly a format string with placeholders for variable data**. Imho if `msg` was supposed to be just a string it would not have been of type `object`. This is a place, where you can investigate further incl. the use of `args`. Inheriting is not really necessary for many cases and a simple `namedtuple` would do just fine.
- `LoggerAdapter` - there is the [contextual information](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info) of a message, which can contain arbitrary data (from what I understand). You will need a custom adapter to work with that.

In addition you will probably have to use a custom `Formatter` and/or `Handler`. Worst case you will have to use some arbitrary string message while passing the extra data (binary or otherwise) alongside it.

Here is a quick and dirty example, where I use a `namedtuple` to hold the extra data. Note that I was unable to just pass the extra data without an actual message but you might be able to go around this issue if you implement your actual custom `LogRecord`. Also note that I am omitting the rest of my code since this is just a demonstration for customization:

```
TensorBoardLogRecord = namedtuple('TensorBoardLogRecord' , 'dtime lvl src msg tbdata')
TensorBoardLogRecordData = namedtuple('tbdata', 'image images scalar scalars custom_scalars')


class TensorBoardLoggerHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, level=logging.INFO, tboard_dir='./runs') -> None:
        super().__init__(level)
        self.tblogger = SummaryWriter(tboard_dir)

    def emit(self, record: TensorBoardLogRecord) -> None:
        # For debugging call print record.__dict__ to see how the record is structured
        # If record contains Tensorboard data, add it to TB and flush
        if hasattr(record, 'args'):
            # TODO Do something with the arguments

    ...

class TensorBoardLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name: str='TensorBoardLogger', level=logging.INFO, tboard_dir='./runs') -> None:
        super().__init__(name, level)
        self.handler = TensorBoardLoggerHandler(level, tboard_dir)
        self.addHandler(self.handler)

    ...


logging.setLoggerClass(TensorBoardLogger)
logger = logging.getLogger('TensorBoardLogger')
logger.info('Some message', TensorBoardLogRecordData(None, None, 10000, None, None))
```

What I am trying to do is add the ability to the logger (still work in progress) to actually write a Tensorboard (in my case from the PyTorch utilities module) log entry that can be visualized via the tool inside the web browser. Yours doesn't need to be that complicated. This "solution" is mostly in case you can't find a way to override the `msg` handling.

I found also this repository - [visual logging](https://github.com/dchaplinsky/visual-logging/blob/master/demo.py), which uses the `logging` facilities of the Python module to handle images. Following the code provided by the repo I was able to get

```
<LogRecord: TensorBoardLogger, 20, D:\Projects\remote-sensing-pipeline\log.py, 86, "TensorBoardLogRecord(image=None, images=None, scalar=1, scalars=None, custom_scalars=None)">

{'name': 'TensorBoardLogger', 'msg': TensorBoardLogRecord(image=None, images=None, scalar=1, scalars=None, custom_scalars=None), 'args': (), 'levelname': 'INFO', 'levelno': 20, 'pathname': 'D:\\Projects\\remote-sensing-pipeline\\log.py', 'filename': 'log.py', 'module': 'log', 'exc_info': None, 'exc_text': None, 'stack_info': None, 'lineno': 86, 'funcName': '<module>', 'created': 1645193616.9026344, 'msecs': 902.6343822479248, 'relativeCreated': 834.2068195343018, 'thread': 6508, 'threadName': 'MainThread', 'processName': 'MainProcess', 'process': 16208}
```

by just calling

```
logger = TensorBoardLogger(tboard_dir='./LOG')
logger.info(TensorBoardLogRecord(image=None, images=None, scalar=1, scalars=None, custom_scalars=None))
```

where I changed `TensorBoardLogRecord` to be

```
TensorBoardLogRecord = namedtuple('TensorBoardLogRecord' , 'image images scalar scalars custom_scalars')
```

As you can see the `msg` is my object `TensorBoardLogRecord`, which confirms both my statement above as well as the statement in the documentation - as long as you customize your logging properly, you can log whatever you want. In the case of the repo I've pointed at the author is using images, which are `numpy` objects. However ultimately those images are read from image files hence binary data is also there.